# In lambda using node.js how can I parse the data from a kinesis stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have the following lambda function set up with kinesis as its event source. The data is coming through as a stream, here I am parsing this to come through as a string e.g. `{id=2, sourceIp=220.220.1.220 }`. I want to convert this to an object in node.js. How can I do this?

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {

    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        var data = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        console.log('data: ', data)
    });
};
```

Comment: shouldnt you be logging `data` instead of `buffer` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the actual output of Kinesis but I'm a bit confused by the example you've given. The test example test even in lambda shows the Kinesis object looking like this

```
"kinesis": {
    "partitionKey": "partitionKey-3",
    "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IDEyMy4=",
    "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "sequenceNumber": "49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961"
}
```

Which means the parsed string should look something like `"id=2,sourceIp=220.220.1.220"` from your example. If that is the case you could do something convoluted like this to get the data into a proper object.

```
var json = {};
data.split(',').map(function(each){
    return each.split('=');
}).forEach(function(pair){
    json[pair[0]] = pair[1];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64'));
```